# Scrape rating stars using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to scrape product data from a marketplace that is using angularjs (https://paytm.com/shop/p/masha-brown-cotton-night-wear-APPMASHA-BROWN-BBOY22296974F0BD7?src=grid&tracker=%7C%7C%7C%7C%2Fg%2Fwomen%2Flingerie-sleepwear%2Fnight-dresses-nighties%7C5845%7C8).

I am able to fetch most of the details using selenium python like this:-

```
import platform
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time

# Phantomjs path
if platform.system() == 'Windows':
    PHANTOMJS_PATH = './phantomjs.exe'
else:
    PHANTOMJS_PATH = './phantomjs'

browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(PHANTOMJS_PATH)
browser.get('https://paytm.com/shop/p/masha-brown-cotton-night-wear-APPMASHA-BROWN-BBOY22296974F0BD7?src=grid&tracker=%7C%7C%7C%7C%2Fg%2Fwomen%2Flingerie-sleepwear%2Fnight-dresses-nighties%7C5845%7C8')
time.sleep(3)
element = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("h1[class='dotted-border']");
title = element.text
print title

element1 = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("span[ng-if='!product.product.isOnlyCarCategory']");
price = element1.text
price = int(price.replace('Buy for Rs ',''))
print price

element2 = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("a[ng-click='product.sendSellerTracking(product.product.merchant.merchant_name)']");
seller_name = element2.text
print seller_name

element3 = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@class='shown-image active']/img");
img_url = element3.get_attribute('src')
print img_url

element4 = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("span[class='rating-text']");
vendor_rating = element4.text
print vendor_rating
```

But now I want to scrape these rating stars [image: Vendor rating stars]

using selenium python. I am new to scraping so can't figure out how we can scrape the UI elements as it is and then make it visible on another web page. I've searched a lot but unable to find anything suitable for my query. So it would be great if someone can help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: you want to scrape the html for those stars ?

Comment: @HassanMehmood yeah exactly

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. You've already found a text representation of those stars (`3.6 /5 (126 ratings)`), so what exactly are you looking for? If you want to display those stars on your own website then it would be best to write your own code to graphically represent `3.6/5`. If you try to copy the stars from that website to yours, there's an infinite number of things that can go wrong.

Comment: @Rawing okay so you are saying that I should display the stars using my own html and provide the scraped value in it

Comment: Yes. If you try to copy the existing HTML then you'll find out that you need to copy parts of the CSS as well, and then you'll probably also want to remove the javascript that is executed on mouseover, and who knows how many other problems would arise. Writing your own HTML is probably a lot easier.

Comment: @Rawing oh okay thanks